# HTML Escape in PHP, can't figure it out

Tags: php

It may be a stupid question but I really can't figure it out ... I need to convert a string to html entities, let's take for example:

"cTm ❂ oNe"

If I use http://www.freeformatter.com/html-escape.html#ad-output to convert it I get: `"cTm &#10050; oNe"` which is what I need but if I use php: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/

```
$x = 'cTm ❂ oNe';
echo htmlentities($x);
```

Tried in CLI as well:

```
$ cat test2; echo ""; echo ""; php test2
<?php

$x = 'cTm ❂ oNe';
echo htmlentities($x);
?>


cTm ❂ oNe
```

without a success, what I'm doing wrong here ?
Thank you!

```
$ php -v
PHP 5.4.45-0+deb7u2 (cli) (built: Oct 17 2015 08:26:31)
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with the ionCube PHP Loader (enabled) + Intrusion Protection from ioncube24.com (unconfigured) v5.0.15, Copyright (c) 2002-2015, by ionCube Ltd.
```

Comment: website is converting htmlentities, on http://www.freeformatter.com/html-escape.html#ad-output i get the escaped version

Comment: Just tested `❂` and it looks like there may be a bug because it's not encoding it for me either.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation on the [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) function, PHP versions 5.6 and greater use UTF-8 encoding, but versions prior to that use ISO-8859-1. You may need to call it with the optional argument for encoding specified.

```
$x = 'cTm ❂ oNe';
echo htmlentities($x, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: already tried that, doesn't work!